# Making os.walk work in a non-standard way

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm trying to do the following, in this order:

Use `os.walk()` to go down each directory.
Each directory has `subfolders`,  but I'm only interested in the first `subfolder`. So the directory looks like:

```
/home/RawData/SubFolder1/SubFolder2
```

For example. I want, in RawData2, to have folders that stop at the SubFolder1 level.

The thing is, it seems like `os.walk()` goes down through ALL of the `RawData` folder, and I'm not certain how to make it stop.

The below is what I have so far - I've tried a number of other combinations of substituting variable dirs for root, or files, but that doesn't seem to get me what I want.

```
import os 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/RawData"): 

    os.chdir("/home/RawData2/")
    make_path("/home/RawData2/"+str(dirs))
```

Comment: It's not clear that what you mean, can you explain more?

Comment: Well, os.walk() goes through all levels of RawData and associated subfolders. I'm interested in it only going down one level, instead of all of them. Maybe a different function would be more appropriate?

Comment: Maybe [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/glob.html#module-glob) would be a useful alternative?

Comment: So you mean that you just have the path of root and the name of that sub-folder right?

Comment: Yeah, so instead of keeping the entire structure, of SubFolder1/SubFolder2/SubFolder3, capping it at SubFolder1. Eventually, I'm going to take all files that are in SubFolders1,2,3 and put them into this new folder instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use glob instead.

As the help on glob describes:

```
glob(pathname)
    Return a list of paths matching a pathname pattern.

    The pattern may contain simple shell-style wildcards a la
    fnmatch. However, unlike fnmatch, filenames starting with a
    dot are special cases that are not matched by '*' and '?'
    patterns.
```

So, your pattern is every first level directory, which I *think* would be something like this:

```
/root_path/*/sub_folder1/sub_folder2
```

So, you start at your root, get everything in that first level, and then look for `sub_folder1/sub_folder2`. I *think* that works.

To put it all together:

```
from glob import glob

dirs = glob('/root_path/*/sub_folder1/sub_folder2')

# Then iterate for each path
for i in dirs:
    print(i)
```

Comment: The thing is, I need sub_folder2 to be something which iterates over a bunch of different folders. I am unsure if your method would do that.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you want to go through all the subdirectories of the filtered match? So if you filtered out /root_path/*/sub1/sub2. Then you want to take each of those and iterate each of those for everything else in those paths?

Answer (score 1):

**Beware**: Documentation for `os.walk` says:

> don’t change the current working directory between resumptions of walk(). walk() never changes the current directory, and assumes that its caller doesn’t either

so you should avoid `os.chdir("/home/RawData2/")` in the `walk` loop.

You can easily ask `walk` not to recurse by using `topdown=True` and clearing `dirs`:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/RawData", True):
    for rep in dirs:
        make_path(os.join("/home/RawData2/", rep )
        # add processing here
    del dirs[]  # tell walk not to recurse in any sub directory
```

Comment: I'll be trying this in a moment. Will report back on how it goes.

Comment: Well, this is better inasmuch it now produces the "SubFolder1", but it still produces all folders on the SubFolder2 level as well.

Comment: @ZR: I should have tested it. A list is a mutable object, but `l = []` does not change the original list but just make the reference point to an empty list. It should be `del l[:]`. Post edited